# Use Service Inside BroadcastReceiver with periodic task In Android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, periodic-task

I tried to start a `Service` inside a `BroadcastReceiver`. The `BroadcastReceiver` receives `BOOT_COMPLETED`. I need to start the `Service` periodically. I have tried the code below:

The `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class SainarReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        App.setContext(context);
        ExceptionHelpers.dLog("SainrCoService", SainarReceiver.class.getSimpleName() + " on Receive : " + App.getString(R.string.app_name));
        SainarService sainarService = new SainarService(context);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(context , sainarService.getClass());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, 1000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

The `Service`:
    public class SainarService extends Service {

```
    public SainarService(){

    }
    public SainarService(Context iContext){
        this.iContext = iContext;
        App.setContext(iContext);
        ExceptionHelpers.dLog("SainrCoService", SainarService.class.getSimpleName() + " Constructor : " + App.getString(R.string.app_name));
    }
    private Context iContext;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // ExceptionHelpers.dLog("SainrCoService", SainarService.class.getSimpleName() + " on Bind : " + App.getString(R.string.app_name));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ExceptionHelpers.dLog("SainrCoService", SainarService.class.getSimpleName() + " on Create : " + App.getString(R.string.app_name));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        ExceptionHelpers.dLog("SainrCoService", SainarService.class.getSimpleName() + " on Start : " + App.getString(R.string.app_name));
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ExceptionHelpers.dLog("SainrCoService", SainarService.class.getSimpleName() + " on Start Command : " + App.getString(R.string.app_name));
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

The manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver
    android:name="com.emaarit.app.sainarco.receivers.SainarReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.emaarit.app.sainarco.receivers.SainarService"/>
```

On `BOOT_COMPLETED` the `BroadcastReceiver` gets started but the `Service` doesn't! Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: Add permisssion <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> for the receiver

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal I did it, but not works !

Comment: i hope u have put that permission outside the application tag.

Comment: yes, permission out of  Application tag, and Receiver and Service  Inside Application tag

Comment: The OP said the BroadcastReceiver works, that means it's not the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PendingIntent.getService()` instead of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` of the `PendingIntent` refers to a `Service`, as it does in your case.

Have a look at the official docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent, int).

Also there is no need to instantiate the service here:

```
SainarService sainarService = new SainarService(context);
```

You should be able to just do:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(context , SainarService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```